# Get height of content in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsscrollview

Is there a way to get the height of the content in an `NSTableView`. In iOS, you can use the `-contentSize` method of `UIScrollView`. However, the `-contentSize` method of `NSScrollView` seems to just return the height of only the visible section of the `NSScrollView`, not including whatever is offscreen.

So, how can this be done on a Mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`- (NSSize)contentSize` in `Appkit` returns the size of the `NSClipView`, and not the height of the content that scrolls inside the table view. I don't know how `UIScrollView`s work, but on OS X, an `NSScrollView` has a "content view" (more aptly named the `NSClipView`) that clips the actual content, which is provided by a document view (scrollable if it has a size larger than that of the clip view) that is a subview of the clip view.

As a side note, the `NSScrollView` scrolls by setting the document view's bounds origin (to the best of my knowledge).

It looks like what you want is the height of the document view, the height of the actual content. For that, try something like

```
scrollView.documentView.frame.size.height
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this also includes space of previously removed rows.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the real content height of NSTableView by

- Objective-C version:
  `tableView.intrinsicContentSize.height`
- Swift version:  `tableView.intrinsicContentSize.height`