# Why does UITableViewCell always resize from 400 to 320 in storyboard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, storyboard, xcode6

I'm working in XCode 6 for iOS 8 and portrait iPhone 5,6,6+. In Storyboard I set "Compact" width and "Regular" height, so my layout views' sizes are 400*800.
I created a `UITableViewController` with custom `UITableViewCell`s, that are prototypes, also via storyboard. Config cell and set constraints work okay, no yellow warnings in storyboard.

Then I reload XCode and all my labels, images, and buttons inside the cell are shifted -80 by "y" and have warnings, however the content view for cell still has a width of 400.

It's looks like this:

[image: The problem]
(http://prntscr.com/5d8snp)

This behavior is observed for all my `UITableView`s. Can you suggest something? In code I also didn't do anything, it's all in storyboard and UITableView.

Comment: You can try to make changes as given in the link below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595118/resizing-uitableview-to-fit-content

Comment: You can try to make changes as given in the link below: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights