# SWIFT UITableview set autoheight according to contents - XCode - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

Automatically adjust the height of `UITableView` according to Contents Dynamically.
I tried the following solution but didn't work for me:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        //This code will run in the main thread:
        CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
        frame.size.height = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
        self.tableView.frame = frame;
    }
```

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595118/resizing-uitableview-to-fit-content)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was having the same issue. i have solved it by simply passing the `UITableView` content height to `UITabelView` frame Height.

```
    func UITableView_Auto_Height()
    {
        if(self.UITableView.contentSize.height < self.UITableView.frame.height){
            var frame: CGRect = self.UITableView.frame;
            frame.size.height = self.UITableView.contentSize.height;
            self.UITableView.frame = frame;
        }
    }
```

Call the above function in `viewDidAppear` function of your `viewController`.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        UITableView_Auto_Height();
    }
```

Comment: what if 2 different table view exist on one controller?

Answer (score 2):

```
 BAD::if(self.UITableView.contentSize.height < self.UITableView.frame.height){
 GOOD::if(self.UITableView.contentSize.height > self.UITableView.frame.height){
```