# Set dynamic Height of view according to height of tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic, autolayout

I want to create a view like this. For that I took one view. Inside it, label(Specification) and then for data of specification I took one tableView. Data for specification could be 2,5,7 anything. Means I am getting array of specification, which could have any no. of elements. Now I want to set height of this view according to height of tableView and after this specification block I have another block which has y position according to specification view. How can I do this?

[image]

[image: image2]
This is the image of output what I am getting. I don't want this scroll in tableView, instead of that  I want it show with its maximum height in view.

Comment: Try setting a height constraint on the table view, and change its constant in code based on the number of cells times the cell height.

Comment: how can I change height of table and view both??. I tried but my view's height is not changed.

Comment: I'm not sure this will solve your issue. But what you could try is creating a height constraint on your table view in your storyboard. Then, create an outlet for the constraint by selecting it and control+dragging to your view controller. Give the constraint outlet a name like tableViewHeightConstraint. In your view controller, set tableViewHeightConstraint.constant to the desired height (number of cells * cell height).

Comment: I have added my code.. I tried in your way, but I am not able to do that. and I also have question that if I want to change my view's height according to table, what constraints should I give?

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't work. I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This answer is right, but I need to add only this line. self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: Nice, glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can set relation of the height constraint of tableView as `<=`. So that it will automatically adjust the height of the tableView, according to the data.

Comment: If possible can you share the code. Will see where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Change the `UITableView` height after loading the content in table using GCD.

Inner view of `UITableView` is based on `ContentSize` and outer view is based on frame size so just change frame size same as `ContentSize`. Outer frame size depend on super view frame size but inner view size is depend on content.

Follow the selected answer in [Resizing UITableView to fit content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2595291/3633534)

Hope it will help you.