# How to stop uitableview after all the rows are done

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, constraints

The title might not be so clear but it was really hard to express it so I will do my best to explain here.

Look at this image:

[image]

I want the `UITableView` to stop entirely after all the rows are done. Meaning after the footer there should be no more white view.

I think what is causing this is the constraints that i have put. But I need my constraints to make it look good in all possible sizes etc. So my question is how can something like this be solved?  I am using SWIFT.

Comment: Try give your `tableview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor` and `cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor` Programatically.

Comment: This actually worked fine. Thank you for this sneaky method. But learning a way to do it properly would be nicer. But love your answer @NiravDoctorwala

Comment: Maybe answer for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595118/resizing-uitableview-to-fit-content) will help.

Answer (score 1):

This worked like a charm. Thank you @tahavath for pointing me to this direcation

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        //This code will run in the main thread:
        var frame = self.tableView.frame;
        frame.size.height = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
        self.tableView.frame = frame;
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

It does work however this will be a problem if the table is bigger than the screen. When trying to run this on iphone 4s it looked terrible.

Comment: You can add output screen for clarity future visitors of the post. That would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code... 
Just include the following code... give your table view an automatic dimension.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Also add the following code where the view loads

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 89
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

and then you set

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

## Edit (not sneaky approach)

```
tableView.frame.size.height = tableView.contentSize.height
```

But there is a problem, if the screen height is not enough to contain tableView content, it will be bad.

#### Here's the right way

```
tableView.frame.size.height = 
    tableView.contentSize.height > UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height ? UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height : tableView.contentSize.height
```

Comment: Yea, Another guy already commented it my question exactly that. It did work but i am looking for a solution that will work in the future to. This seems like a sneaky way of doing it.

Comment: @TimoCengiz check my updated answer for iPhone 4s problem

Comment: Not working. Part of the tableview is still outside bounds

Answer (score -1):

Because the table thinks there is a footer to show, it doesn't display any cells beyond those you explicitly asked for.

Set a zero height table footer view in your `viewDidLoad` method

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

Or

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```