# Resizing UITableView to fit content on ios 11

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios11, uitableviewautomaticdimension

Given the junk contentSize in UITableView on ios 11 how to I get a tableview with variable height cells to autosize to that content?

Answers here: [Resizing UITableView to fit content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595118/resizing-uitableview-to-fit-content)
have rotted and no longer apply to ios 11

Comment: Did you find any solution to this one?

Comment: no, I have a cobweb of mess which does not compute intrinsiccontentsize for uitableview reliably, estimatedRowHeight affects the looks, not just performance

Answer (score 4):

It looks like when `UITableView` is using Automatic Dimensions - `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, it  calculates the `contentSize` **dynamically** - as you scroll.

So the solution is to catch those changes using KVO:

```
var contentSizeObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    contentSizeObservation = tableView.observe(\.contentSize, options: [.new], changeHandler: { tableView, value in
        // Do the setup here, this will be called multiple times
    })
}
```

### Important

**You need to define the `contentSizeObservation` as global (as a class member), or else the `changeHandler` block won't get called because the variable will get cleared by ARC.**