# How to set dynamic table height based on table row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, row-height

I am facing table height issue at run time.

I have a Scroll View added to my Super view. Over the Scroll View, I have added a UIView in the top then after UIView I have placed one UITableView (scrollEnabled false) and again have added a UIView in the bottom of my UITableView.

Problem: I want user to do a single scroll in the screen, so I have disabled table view scrolling property. Now my problem is I am fetching table array data from server so after getting data from server, my viewDidLayoutSubviews method is not getting called where I have wrote the table height logic. And when I am re-loading the same screen then everything is working fine.

Here is my code :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        if devicesArray.count != 0{
            viewDeviceList.frame = CGRect(x: viewDeviceList.frame.origin.x, y: viewDeviceList.frame.origin.y, width: viewDeviceList.frame.size.width, height: tableDeviceList.contentSize.height)

            tableDeviceList.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

Can anyone suggest me on this. Thank you.

Comment: So you want a table view that grows and shrinks dynamically depending on the rows? If so, you can do something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55068380/10473781

Comment: when you get your data from server : try, tableView.reloadData() and then self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: Hi @KeshuRaiI have added the self.view.layoutIfNeeded() below to reloading my tableview. But the height of table view is incorrect.

Comment: I would have preferred this structure: https://imgur.com/X2jybHZ . This way you don't need to worry about height and scroll view. Tableview will take care of everything.

Comment: Okay, Can you please check my logic of viewDidLayoutSubviews? Am I correct?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qjABDqK this is when I am fetching table data from server.

Comment: try this -> https://medium.com/infancyit/a-simple-solution-for-self-sizing-tableview-with-auto-resizing-cell-a3f82c4a1b34

Comment: @AnandGautam You can try with tableView height constraint. tableHeightConstraint = rowHeight * arrayCount

Comment: Hi @A.H.NuriI have added my table view to a UIView. And I am setting up to viewHeightConstraints.constant = tableView.contentSize.height

Comment: But very first time my tableView.contentSize value is incorrect,

Comment: I can't set  tableHeightConstraint = rowHeight * arrayCount, as my rowHeight values are changing at rum time.

Comment: @AnandGautam Please check my Answer. I tried with observer. That's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with below code and let me know. I'm working with observer and its working perfectly.

```
//MARK:- Add this observer into your View/Controlloer
        override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
            self.transactionTableViewHeightConstraints.constant = transactionTableView.contentSize.height
        }
//MARK:- Fetch TableListData
    func updateTableViewHeightAfterAPICall(){
            self.transactionTableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: [], context: nil)
            self.transactionTableView.reloadData()
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create outlet for tableView height constraint like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

add this line

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
```