# Autolayout UITableView expand parent view but not greater than safe area

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a Storyboard which has a simple view hierarchy:

```
- View (has top/bottom constraints relative to safeArea >= 30, centerY)
   - Label (has height/top(SuperView)/bottom(TextField) constraints)
   - TextField (has height/top(Label)/bottom(TableView) constraints)
   - TableView (has height >= 0, top(TextField)/bottom(Superview) constraints)
```

Inside the UITableViewDelegate (cellForRowAt):

```
tableView.setNeedsLayout()
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

The behaviour I wish to achieve is to have the TableView and the parent View grow as new records are added to it. However, the parent view should not exceed its top/bottom constraints relative to the safe area.

All the elements have height constrains and spacing explicitly set, except for the table view (which has height >= 0). As well, the parent's view content hugging priority is 250 and the tableview compression resistance is 750. I thought that fixing the height constraints and spacing between elements would allow the tableview to grow up to some point because the content compression resistance is higher for the top/bottom safe area constraints than it is for the TableView.

However, XCode is forcing me to set a height or a Y position constraint for the parent view. I can't do that because then the view cannot grow automatically.

I would prefer to stick with AutoLayout and wondering if anyone has an idea or resource on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table views do not automatically set their height based on the number of rows.

You can use this custom table view class (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48623673/6257435):

```
final class ContentSizedTableView: UITableView {
    override var contentSize:CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
    }
}
```

This will "auto-size" your table view whenever the content size changes. To use it, add a table view and set its class to `ContentSizedTableView`.

- Constrain the top, leading and trailing as desired.
- Constrain the bottom to `>= 0` to the bottom of the superview (or `>= 8` if you want it to stop 8-pts from the bottom, or whatever value you want for your layout).
- Give it a height constraint - doesn't really matter what, but using a value such as `100` let's you see it as you work with the layout.
- Then ***edit that height constraint*** and check the **Placeholder - Remove at build time** checkbox.

The table view's height constraint will be removed when you run the app, and the `ContentSizedTableView` will automatically grow until it reaches the bottom constraint.

Comment: Thank you, this works well. Is there a way to animate the parent view expadning when the table view size increases?