# Xamarin.iOS native - Resizing UITableView after Content. ContentHeight is always 0

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have been following this guide: [Resizing UITableView to fit content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595118/resizing-uitableview-to-fit-content/48623673#48623673) in order for the UiTableView to adjust its height after its content.

In the ViewDidLoad() method, I am filling my uiTable so it has 3 rows. So the content height should not be 0.

Do you have any ideas of what could be wrong?

This is my class:

```
public partial class ContentSizedTableView : UITableView
{
    public ContentSizedTableView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }   

    public override CGSize ContentSize { get => base.ContentSize; set => InvalidateIntrinsicContentSize(); }

    public override CGSize IntrinsicContentSize
    {
        get
        {
            LayoutIfNeeded();
            return new CGSize(NoIntrinsicMetric, ContentSize.Height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can refer to this officail document about auto-size：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/tables/autosizing-row-height

Comment: Hi thanks, Maybe it was unclear but it is the UITableView not the rows that I want to be automatically sized. I have a UiTableview inside a scrollview and I want the table height to be equal to the height of the content @AdrainZhu-MSFT